# Rails form_for partial rendering both failed validation and correct validation

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I'm using a form_for remote:true in my view with a few validations, which triggers a JS response to append a partial to a div:

index.html.erb

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for @reservation, html: { id: "createReservationForm", method: :post }, remote: true do |f| %>
  <div id="error_div"></div>
  <%= f.datetime_select :start_time, ampm: true, discard_minute: true, :minute_step => 60 %>
  <%= f.select :party_size, (1..6).map { |i| [i,i] } %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, required: true %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :restaurant_id, value: @restaurant.id %>
  <%= f.submit 'Create Reservation', id: "formSubmit" %>
<% end %>
```

reservations_controller.rb

```
def create
    @reservation = Reservation.new(reservation_params)
    @reservation.start_time = @reservation.start_time.beginning_of_hour
    @reservation.end_time = @reservation.start_time + 1.hour

    respond_to do |format|
      if @reservation.save
        format.html { render action: 'index' }
        format.js   { render action: 'create', status: :created, location: @reservation }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'index' }
        format.js   { render action: 'create', status: :unprocessable_entity, errors: @reservation.errors.full_messages }
      end
    end
  end
```

reservation.rb

```
  validates :start_time, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :party_size, presence: true
  validate  :not_past

  def not_past
    if start_time.past?
      errors.add :start_time, "cannot be in past"
    end
  end
```

create.js.erb

```
$("#createReservationForm").on("ajax:success", function(e, data, status, xhr) {
  $("#error_div").html('');
  $("#reservationList").prepend("<%= j render partial: 'reservation', locals: { reservation: @reservation } %>")
  $("#createReservationForm")[0].reset();
  return false;
}).on("ajax:error", function(e, xhr, status, error) {
  $("#error_div").html("<%= j render partial: 'shared/error_messages', locals: { object: @reservation } %>")
  return false;
});
```

The issue I'm having is when I say, submit a form that fails the 'not_past' validation, I get the error message and it doesn't submit. Then, when I adjust the time on the form so that it passes the 'not_past' validation, it appends both the new @reservation, as well as the previously submitted one that failed the validation. Is there a way to somehow 'clear' the previous one that failed so that when a user adjusts the time on the form to pass the validation, it only appends that version of it?

I've tried messing with the 'return false;', I've tried setting @reservation to nil in the controller before creating a new one, I also did puts "@reservation" in the respond_to block and it only gave me the correct one, so I'm not sure where the incorrect one is being held.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone encounters the same issue, I found it can be solved by removing the "ajax:success" and "ajax:error" code. I can't attest as to why it was preventing it from working properly, I just know it was able to fix it.